# How many quartic polynomials have single-digit integer coefficients?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

> Let $X$ be the set of all polynomials of degree 4 in a single variable $t$ such that every coefficient is a single-digit nonnegative integer. Find the
>   cardinality of $X$.

This is a question from Balakrishnan's Intro. Discrete Mathematics, and it's an even-numbered exercise, so I can't see if my solution is correct.

Let $$t_i\ (i = 1, 2,\ldots,k)$$ be the coefficients in a polynomial with $k$ terms. Then, $$t_k>0\in\mathbb Z$$

The first polynomial can be expressed as:
$$t_1^4 + t_2^3 + t_3^2 + t_4$$
the second
$$t_1^4 + t_2^2 + t_3$$
and so on

I think I can recognize and define a pattern here in that since the polynomials must all be of degree $4$, each polynomial must have $t_k^4$ as a coefficient, correct? So that means that, for each coefficient of the polynomials, there are $9$ possible nonnegative integers. Wouldn't that mean:

$$(1)(9)(9)(9) + (1)(9)(9) + (1)(9) + (1)$$

is the cardinality of $X$?

Comment: You call the $t_i$ the "terms" (coefficients, right?) of a polynomial; why do you take them to powers? There is only one variable, and only the variable is to be taken to powers.

Comment: @anon Whoops, I meant coefficients :)

Comment: Better titles for this question might be "How many quartic polynomials have single-digit integer coefficients?" or "Counting quartic polynomials with single-digit integer coefficients".

Comment: @AntonioVargas Whoops, I think you mean quartic :-)

Comment: @nrpeterson oops, thanks.

Comment: To refresh your perspective, you're counting polynomials of the form $$\square t^4+\square t^3+\square t^2+\square t+\square$$ with each coefficient in $1\le\square\le9$ (that's nine numbers) independently.

Comment: @anon Actually, the coefficients for the terms of degree $\leq 3$ can also be $0$.

Comment: @proximal Maybe, maybe not. Either we take the view that (for the sake of the problem) a coefficient $0$ "doesn't exist" (so we don't even refer to there being a zero coefficient), in which case the latter four $\square$'s can indeed be $0$. Or, we take the view that the coefficients do exist, and since $0$ is not "nonnegative" (as the problem stipulates) it is not allowed.

Comment: @anon $t^4$ is a polynomial of degree $4$ with nonnegative integer coefficients. And since when is $0$ not non-negative?

Comment: Oops, I am being silly and confusing nonnegative with positive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution is off a little bit; and your notation is off a little more!  So, let's see if we can fix that.

A polynomial of degree four in $t$ is an expression of the form
$$
at^4+bt^3+ct^2+dt+f,
$$
where we require that $a\neq 0$.

The choices for $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, and $f$ don't affect eachother; $a$ must be in $1,2,\ldots,9$, and the rest of coefficients must be in $0,1,2,\ldots,9$. (Notice that it said *nonnegative*, not positive!)

So, there are 9 choices for $a$, and 10 choices each for $b$, $c$, $d$, and $f$; that gives us $9\cdot 10^4=90000$ different polynomials of degree 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Helped clarify many things. I got lost in the fog of too-many-new-things thinking ;p

Comment: @JonathanDewein Happens to everybody!  Happy to help.